# PHP SQL Server Insert not working on single table

Tags: php, sql-server

I've done this dozens of times, and for some reason an insert on a specific table in this database keeps failing.   And by that, I mean as far as the PHP code is concerned, it executes just fine, but nothing is actually inserted into the table.

```
$insertQuery =  "INSERT INTO PreAdmission (ProspectID,AnticipatedEntryTermID,PreAdmitDate,UserDefCode,ProgramID,Salutation,FirstName,LastName,Suffix,MiddleInitial,StudentSSN,PreferredName, EventID,HighSchoolID,SourceOfLead,SexCode,Church,ACTComposite,ACTMath,ACTNatSci,ACTSocSci,ACTEnglish,SATMath, SATVerbal,SATTSWE,SATComposite,CampusID,HSGPA1,HSGPA2,HSRank,HSRankOf,PGPAVerbal,PGPAMath, PGPA,ReligionID,NativeLanguageID,DeleteFlag,OrganizationID,PersonalIDNumber,Password) VALUES (14522,0,'2017-02-20 20:54:49',3966,2,'','John','Doe','','','','',0,0,'','Male','',0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'',0,'','')";

$insertResult = sqlsrv_query($link, $insertQuery);
```

I'm testing it out, and there's not much to my code at this point but the above lines and opening the connection.   But I have tried copy and pasting the query directly to SQL server, and it executes just fine if I do it that way.

If I run the exact same code with a different query to insert into another table, that works fine too.

The only other thing I can think of is that there are triggers on this table that go off when an insert occurs.   Mainly just updating other tables.   But that hasn't been an issue in the past.

Comment: Does `sqlsrv_errors()` tell you anything?

Comment: Just Tried it with no results

Comment: Tried running the same query through powershell.  Getting "The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'xp_ctnhash', database 'master', schema 'dbo'."   So appears to be some kind of permission thing.  Although I gave the account all the permission I could find on the db, and still not working.

Comment: Ok, i've got it now.   It was an extended stored procedure in the master dbo that the account needed permission to execute.